# JSON.parse for parsing a json list to javascript array doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm getting a JSON list thanks to this function :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        var idContact = @ViewData["IdPhysique"];
        var Url = "/Accueil/DonneListeFonctionContact";
        $.getJSON(Url, { IdContact: idContact }, function (data) {  

        });

});
```

And I get this JSON:

[image: json screenshot]

Now I would like to parse that JSON to an array so I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
        var idContact = @ViewData["IdPhysique"];
        var Url = "/Accueil/DonneListeFonctionContact";
        var data = $.getJSON(Url, { IdContact: idContact }, function (data) {  

        });
        var array = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

But an error appears in Google development tool:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Is there an other way to do that ?

Comment: What you want to do with the returning JSON? like show it on a listview etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to parse it, because jQuery does it for you and passed it to your callback function in the `data` argument. `$.getJSON()` does not *return* the JSON. So:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
    var idContact = @ViewData["IdPhysique"];
    var Url = "/Accueil/DonneListeFonctionContact";
    $.getJSON(Url, { IdContact: idContact }, function (data) {  
        // here data is an array because jQuery already parsed the JSON
        // data.length is what you need to test
    });
 });
```

EDIT: Also the "JSON" response that you show in your question is not valid JSON. Property names must be double-quoted, and so must string values, so it should be:

```
[{"IdFonction":734, "LibellFonction":"Clercs"}, ...
```

Comment: Did you fight hard to get this above the minimum-size limit?

Comment: oh okay, I didn't know but if i don't parse it into an array, how can I get the length of the list ?

Comment: @HubertSolecki `data.length`; `data` is already the array you want

Comment: umm... you shouldn't be suggesting `alert`s for debugging

Comment: @JanDvorak - Actually even before I realised the OP was trying to use the return value of `$.getJSON()` my initial short response was above the minimum size without me thinking about it. Regarding the alert (which I've now removed, sigh) that was just the first thing that came to mind to demonstrate that you can use `data.length`.

Comment: i put **data.length** into an alert to try it and it shows me : **unknown**

Comment: @HubertSolecki definitely not `unknown`; if it is `undefined`, [please show your code](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @HubertSolecki - Did you try to use `data.length` inside the callback function, or are you still trying to use the return from `$.getJSON()` as if it was the data (when it's definitely not)?

Comment: yes it works ! i've just tried **alert(data.length)** inside the function as you showed me @JanDvorak, thanks a lot

Comment: @HubertSolecki pro-tip: use `console.log` for debugging. It doesn't convert the logged object into string

Answer (score 0):

It is already an array since you get it as JSON. You do not need to JSON.parse it!

Comment: Isn't this exactly what nnnnnn had just said?

Comment: @JanDvorak Sorry, i hadn't noticed that since i was editing while nnnnnn posted it!